# Using SVN with multiple users

Tags: svn, repository

We are currently using SVN to handle our code. However, sometimes we all code all at once.

For example 3 people check out the same project. User 1 gets something done and goes to check it in. How can Users 2 and 3 get the update without losing their current work? We've tried the update command but usually yields some errors.

Should we be using something other than SVN?

I am using eclipse's svn repository.

Comment: You shouldn't be losing local changes as a result of `svn update`, but I assume you guys are running into merge conflicts when you do an update - someone changed code that you have you in your local copy and then you have to resolve them locally: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-conflicts.html

Comment: Thanks that makes more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subversion is designed exactly for what you're doing. However, your questions are covered by a basic understanding of how Subversion works. I recommend reading Chapters 1 and 2 of the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).

Also, the errors you're seeing on updates are probably conflicts, which are covered in the book.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Git, but I doubt that the problem is the source code management software.

Which client are you using?  Update shouldn't be yielding errors.  Developers need to learn how to branch, update, merge, and commit code.  It's not always easy, but it's necessary.

A few rules to follow:

1. Check in early and often.  The longer you wait to check in, the more likely collisions and merges will be.
2. Get used to updating frequently.
3. Always update before you commit.

Git can make merges easier, but it doesn't eliminate them.

Comment: Does the update download changes from when you first checked it out? Also are using the SVN repository built into eclipse. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it yields errors it means you made incompatible changes to the same lines of code, which leads to merge conflicts. Whatever VCS you'll use you'll have the same issues, should you be patching the same piece of code in incompatible ways.

VCS doesn't solve your problems with merging always. You need some collaboration rules as to who's working on which part of code and that will solve the merging issues mostly.

Practically, if you experience a merge conflict, you need to resolve it by hand, commit back and let other users update their working copy.